# GAE push queue with max_concurrent_requests

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to set up a push queue with `max_concurrent_requests` set to 1.  So I created a `queue.yaml` like this:

```
queue:
- name: myqueue
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
```

When running in the dev server, I get the error:

```
root: WARNING: Refill rate must be specified for push-based queue. Please check queue.yaml file.
```

Doing a Google search for "refill rate" and queue.yaml doesn't give any relevant hits except for the taskqueue stub, which doesn't help me.

Changing `queue.yaml` to this:

```
queue:
- name: myqueue
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  rate: 10/s
```

Gets rid of the error in the dev server.  Can anyone confirm that this will actually create a queue with a max of 1 concurrent request? (ok, that it is also limited to 10 per second)  I'm suspicious because the `queue.yaml` documentation doesn't address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not specified in the documentation, you must specify a "rate" when creating a queue.  To achieve 1 maximum concurrent request, you can simply set a high rate, and the rate will essentially be ignored.  My tasks take about 0.25 seconds (i.e., 4/s) so a rate of 10/s makes sure that the rate does not impact task execution.